# Перебор DOM элемента как массива

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите что выдала консоль. Так и должно быть или нужно иным способом перебрать массив?

```
<div class="s-far">
    <p>Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p> 
    <p>Commodi illo enim qui in doloremque saepe, ab veniam consequuntur <span>eos</span></p>
</div>
```

Говорю консоле:

```
var spans = $('.s-far span');
for( key in spans ){
    console.log(spans[key])
}
```

Ответ убил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите в консоль значения свойств объекта-обертки jQuery.

```js
var spans = $('.s-far span');
spans.each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-far">
  <p>Lorem ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Commodi illo enim qui in doloremque saepe, ab veniam consequuntur <span>eos</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: А данный вариант возвращает сразу все элементы или перебирает от первого до последнего?

Comment: @Cobret Данный вариант перебирает все элементы, которые попали в выборку `$('.s-far span')`

Comment: @Cobret Не понял. Вы же видите, что выводит каждая строчка консоли. `spans` содержит все найденные DOM-элементы. `$().each` вызывает функцию-параметр для каждого из них.

Comment: А, дошло). Значит по отдельности